# Show or hide a div on selection of dropdown and radio buttion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to write a jQuery where a div is to be shown if a specific option is chosen from dropdown and a specific radio button is clicked. But I am unable to do so.

```
Html
<pre><code>
<html>
</body>
    <select name="Location of positive event" id="dropdown">
        <option value="home">At home</option>
        <option value="commute">On my commute</option>
        <option value="work">At work</option>
        <option value="outside">On the street</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    

    <label>
        Morning
        <input name="time-radio" type="radio" value="1">
        </label>
        <label>
        Evening
        <input name="time-radio" type="radio" value="2">
        </label>
    

    <div id="test">
        <label>
        <input name="test1" value="test!" type="checkbox">
        Test1
        </label>
        <label>
        <input name="test1" value="test@" type="checkbox">
        Test1
        </label>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow! :) You can try on your own [with these tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) and come back if your code would not work

Comment: Start here: https://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We are creating a jquery code for hiding and show a div which is having `id = test`, we are adding a class name `div` and hide it on default. It will be shown when the “`AT Work`” option is selected from the dropdown and also shown when you click the “`Evening`” radio button. You can adjust it according to your requirement.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/xayb9h1p/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".box2").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.box,
.box2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<pre><code>
<html>
<body>
    <select name="Location of positive event" id="dropdown">
      <option>Select</option>
        <option value="home">At home</option>
        <option value="commute">On my commute</option>
        <option value="work">At work</option>
        <option value="outside">On the street</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    

    <label>
        Morning
        <input name="time-radio" type="radio" value="1">
        </label>
        <label>
        Evening
        <input name="time-radio" type="radio" value="2">
        </label>
    

    <div id="test" class="box work ">
    <h2>for Dropdown</h2>
        <label>
        <input name="test1" value="test!" type="checkbox">
        Test1
        </label>
        <label>
        <input name="test1" value="test@" type="checkbox">
        Test2
        </label>
        </div>
        <div id="test1" class="box2  2">
        <h2>for Radio Button</h2>
        <label>
        <input name="test3" value="test!" type="checkbox">
        Test3
        </label>
        <label>
        <input name="test4" value="test@" type="checkbox">
        Test4
        </label>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want the checkboxes to show only if both are selected, not only if 1 element is selected :)